# How to preprocess binary labeled sequences of ordered in time data points to fit into RNN?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I am observing some repeated events which are guaranteed to give a binary outcome on termination and I am doing some data preparation so I can fit it into a model.

Each event has its own properties which are event_id (unique), start time, end time (dates), event_type (categorical) and it's represented as 1D vector. Events usually lasts for 30sec-2mins and I'm sampling its state every 15 seconds, which results in multivariate time series, and a boolean, which represents the outcome of an event.

Currently, I have 3 params for time series. Here's an example of 2D Matrix for some event:

Target: 1

[image]

Another example:

Target: 0

[image]

Input data has shape (n_seq, n_0pad, 3) (3 variables)

My goal is to train a binary classificator on binary labeled sequences of time series, with each sequence having its own properties, to predict the outcome of an event given a time series, its binary label and its properties describing the event.

Is it possible to fit a list of such sequences into an algorithm with additional info, so each event is represented as 2D matrix of time series and a separate vector (with at least one column has unique values and is equal to n_events). I don't know how to concat all these tables into a single training dataset to fit in a model. Should I include event info for each event to its tables' observations and make the shape of time series to be (n_0pad, 3 + n_event_properties)? (i suppose time since event started can be dropped so its gonna be 2 + n_event_prop)
Another question is, is it a good a idea to 0pad with is_event_finished = 1 for next observations if i choose to set each time series length to maximum length of time series among events, so it will look like this:

[image]

Also, what kind of statistical analysis should I dive into to better compare time series data?

I would be very grateful if you would like to share your ideas, relevant resources and articles if you have any. Thank you in advance!